# Round off number to the nearest Highest number from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a requirement where I have an array of number and I also get a new number after some calculation. After getting that new number I need to round it off to the nearest **highest** value from the array. For eg:

var counts = [2,33,61,92,125,153,184,215,245,278,306,335,365]

So if the new number is 35 then it should check from the array and display number 61 and not 33. It should always round off to the highest number from the array.

I tried this but it only returned me the nearest value from the array and not the highest number from the array. May I know where did I go wrong or what extra needs check needs to be done?

```
var counts = [2,33,61,92,125,153,184,215,245,278,306,335,365],
  goal = 35;

var closest = counts.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

Comment: if there was no 61 in the array, would you expect it to return 33 or 92?

Comment: If there was no 61 then I would expect it to return 92 but the values of the array is fixed, it won't change.

Comment: array will be sorted in ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following return the min value among all values in counts greater than goal.

```js
var counts = [2,33,61,92,125,153,184,215,245,278,306,335,365],
  goal = 35;
  
let min = Math.min(...counts.filter( num => num >= goal ));
  
console.log(min)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.find()`

Be sure your array is sorted or this will give you a wrong answer.

```js
var counts = [2,33,61,92,125,153,184,215,245,278,306,335,365]

var goal = 33;

var closest = counts.find(numb => numb >= goal);

console.log(closest);
```

Comment: .find() will work if and only if the counts array are sorted in ascending order. Because it return the first element greater than goal.

Comment: It works as it is supposed to but only the issue with it is that when the number selected is same as that of which is present in the array, it still returns the largest number. If the goal is 33 then it should return 33 from the array and not 61.

Comment: @RaviShah well change `>` to `>=` i have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It will work for both sorted and unsorted arrays.

```js
let countsArr = [2,36,61,92,125,153,184,215,245,278,306,335,365];
const goalValue = 35;
let diff = Number.MAX_VALUE;
const closestMax = countsArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const currDiff = curr - goalValue;
    if((currDiff > diff) || (currDiff < 0)) {
        return acc;
    }
    else {
        diff = currDiff;
        return curr;
    }
});

console.log(closestMax);
```